How to change scatter point color in plotly if exceed/ in between horizontal and vertical lines
Is it possible to change the specific scatter point color in a plot when values is in between the horizontal and vertical line in plot?
Example:
Horizonal Line and Vertical Line Code
Here is the initial Plot with the Horizontal and Vertical Lines:

I want to change the color of these scatter points:

The goal of my code is to change the plots colors in between in horizontal and vertical lines. Is it possible using plotly??
Here are my code:
parameters= st.selectbox("Parameters",("Carbon","Hydrogen","Nitrogen","Sulfur","Oxygen+Others","Moisture"))
parameters == ('Hydrogen'): #Plot in Hydrogen Parameters
 hydrogen= px.scatter(plot_data,x='Calorific Value (kcal/kg)', y='Hydrogen (%)',title='Hydrogen Plot',
                  width=800,height=800,hover_name='Lab')
#Hydrogen Horizontal Line
 h1_hline=hydrogen.add_hline(type='line',y=4, line=dict(color='Red'))    
 h2_hline=hydrogen.add_hline(type='line',y=4.65, line=dict(color='Red'))
 h3_hline=hydrogen.add_hline(type='line',y=6, line=dict(color='Red'))
#Hydrogen Vertical Line
 h1_vline=hydrogen.add_vline(type='line', x=3900,line=dict(color='Red'))
 h2_vline=hydrogen.add_vline(type='line', x=4221,line=dict(color='Red'))
 h3_vline=hydrogen.add_vline(type='line', x=4400,line=dict(color='Red'))

 st.plotly_chart(hydrogen)


can you include the code you used to generate the scatter as formatted text? that will make it easier to help you

There isn't a way to do it with plotly, but you can create a colormap based on their value, since you know the value of lines.
Assuming you want to color the markers with y>=4 and x>=400 differently, and in your dataframe x values are stored in 'col_x' and y values are stored in 'col_y', here is how you can create a colormap:
df['colormap'] = [bool((x>=4000)&(y>=4)) for x,y in zip(df['col_x'],df['col_y'])]

and then setting the colormap as color:
fig = px.scatter(df,x='col_x',y='col_y',color='colormap')
# fig.add_vline...
# fig.add_hline...
fig.show()

